# passing variable in url with smarty

Tags: php, url, get, smarty

here is an existing link

```
<a class="link-item" href="{#url_site#}/plongee-{$post.nom_pays|sluggable}/{$post.nom_forfait|sluggable}-{$post.id_forf}">Voir l'offre</a>
```

I am trying to pass a variable to the next page.
I have added:

```
<a class="link-item" href="{#url_site#}/plongee-{$post.nom_pays|sluggable}/{$post.nom_forfait|sluggable}-{$post.id_forf}?test=test">Voir l'offre</a>
```

the next page url is

```
         http://dev.amv-voyages.fr/plongee-egypte/dune-sejour-plongee-petit-budget-safaga-sans-vols-1387?test=test
```

but

```
echo '<pre>get';
print_r($_GET);
echo '</pre>';
```

returns empty.

Please help :)

Comment: I think you should add `QSA` (Query String Append) to your htaccess rules.

Comment: that's interesting but i would not know where to place it in the .ht access file...there is many RewriteRule . I have placed it where i reckon it should be but that gives me a 500 serveur error

Comment: `[QSA]` is the syntax, and you have to place it were the rewrite occurs (that rule)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="link-item" href="{#url_site#}/plongee-{$post.nom_pays|sluggable}/{$post.nom_forfait|sluggable}-{$post.id_forf}&test=test">Voir l'offre</a>
```

Please try this as already there are multiple slashes it means in the rewrite rule already the '?' is used to take the first parameter so all other parameters should use '&' after the first one.

Comment: then please once check the rewrite rule for the next page you are redirecting may be the rule is not written to accept more parameters